# Suggested text/auto correct not working - MS Lumia 640 LTE Dual SIM

Tags: windows-10-mobile, autocorrect, lumia-640

So. I upgraded my phone to Windows 10 Mobile (Insider Preview) a couple of months ago (from Windows Phone 8.1).

About a week ago, the suggested text/auto correct feature has stopped working. Yes, I checked in settings, but that shows that the feature is available (it isn't, that's why i'm asking).

**Has anyone else has these issues or knows the solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Mobile sometimes deviates from the settings of WP8.1 and it is very common for Bluetooth as well. What you can do is:

1. Update your phone to the latest build of OS.
2. Make sure  that keyboard stuff for your selected language is downloaded. If not go to language settings and add that keyboard.
3. Long tap the lower right toggle key of keyboard then go to settings to check whether your keyboard is downloaded or not.
   4.Once downloaded you can tap the keyboard to change it's settings. It's where you can find whether text suggestions are turned on or not.
4. Finally you can perform a restart after all settings are right at there place.

Hopefully it helps as it resolved keyboard issue for me (I am running 14393.479).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but the issue was resolved yesterday - the functions randomly came back whilst I was typing a text! Makes me question the reliability of windows phones...

Comment: Actually, i'm an idiot. I was using the US keyboard, which was not fully downloaded, instead of the UK one, which was.

Comment: That's why I said **Make sure that keyboard stuff for your selected language is downloaded. If not go to language settings and add that keyboard.** well I'm glad that your problem is resolved